# support and lift for fp-growth rules in mllib spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to extract support and lift for generated association rules with fp-growth. Having found the rules with the code below I manually go through the transactions and calculate support and lift. I wonder if there is a more legant way to extract this info. thanks!

```
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}

val minConfidence = 0.8
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).collect().foreach { rule =>
  println(
    rule.antecedent.mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + " => " + rule.consequent .mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + ", " + rule.confidence)
}
```

Comment: There's a JIRA ticket for it, I just asked for re-opening it. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10697

Answer (score 1):

mm not elegant but this is what I do

```
val freqs = fpgrowth_model(transactions, min_supp=supp)
val supps = freqs.withColumn("support", $"freq" / total_transactions)
val rules = get_rules(transactions, min_supp=supp, min_confidence=conf)
val cross_df = supps.join(rules, $"items" === $"consequent")
               .withColumn("lift",$"confidence" / $"support")
```